# Android Gallery Full width, no gap

Tags: android, stream, gallery

I need to build something like a stream for my android app (like pulse)
I tried several horizontalListview or HorizontalScrollView but it's not smooth at all!

The smoother widget I found is the gallery.

I successfully tweaked it to right align:

http://cl.ly/0a3Q002u3H1f3w2l0g2e

My problem is when you scroll max to the right. It looks like stream #3.
Is there a way change this to avoid the gap on the right ?

Maybe to changing the maximum selectable position (# of elements - 4 in my case)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I use this one https://github.com/vieux/Android-Horizontal-ListView

I found the problem about smoothness. The vertical listview shouldn't react when we are already scrolling a stream horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like

```
public class GalleryChild extends Gallery {

...

@Override public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
    if (getSelectedItemPosition() >= getChildCount() - BUFFER) {
        setSelection(getChildCount() - BUFFER, true);
        /** Eat the event. */
        return true;
    } else return super.onScroll(e1, e2, distanceX, distanceY);
}
```